# From where does the particle in liquid get energy to move always?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, radiation

My question is that if there is an object,then without giving energy to an object it cannot move …so my question is that how do particles in fluids always move without giving them any additional energy??

Answer (score 1):

> if there is an object,then without giving energy to an object it cannot move

This is an incorrect premise. Here are some counter examples:

1. the object could be initially moving already. Then by Newton’s 1st law it will continue to move without giving it energy.
2. the object could initially be at rest. Then we could transform to a different reference frame where it is moving. Coordinate transformations don’t require energy.
3. the object could use some internal energy, like a compressed spring, chemical energy etc. Then it would move without being given energy.

> how do particles in fluids always move without giving them any additional energy?

They are initially moving. But it is not true that they don’t get any additional energy. They are frequently colliding and giving and receiving energy.